# Will mysql still use my indexes if they use underscore

Tags: mysql

Say I have an index on a name field in the database.  I remember reading that if I do:

`where name like 'Jon%'` that it will still use the index, 
however if I do

`where name like '%Jon%'` then it cannot use the index and therefore results in a full table scan.
If I use

`where name like '__Jon%'` can it use the index, or does it have to use a full scan and therefore the underscore is just as bad as the percent sign for response time?

Comment: Just did some describe's on some test queries and it appears to me that _ is no better than % for efficiency.

Comment: [The docs say _wildcard character_](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-indexes.html) and I take that to include `_` as a wildcard, not just `%` "_The index also can be used for LIKE comparisons if the argument to LIKE is a constant string that does not start with a wildcard character._"

Comment: You should feel free to post your own answer if you've done the query `EXPLAIN`s to verify the index wasn't used, together with MySQL's documentation wording I linked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by Michael Berkowski the official documentation states: [The index also can be used for LIKE comparisons if the argument to LIKE is a constant string that does not start with a wildcard character.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-indexes.html)

So wildcard of any kind will eliminate the use of the index and `_` is a wildcard.

Here's some quick screen capture's of explained queries illustrating use/non-use of index:

[image: Show results using a query with an index]

[image]